# Unused Version Info keys in Delphi .dproj file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Using Delphi IDE to handle version info is not an easy task. With help of [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) I have managed to get base version info in the project that will be propagated through all projects platforms/configurations. In this case Win32/Win64.

It seems that `VerInfo_Keys` tag is the one responsible for including correct Version Info in final exe file.

```
<VerInfo_Keys>FileVersion=5.0.0.501;ProductVersion=5.0;CompanyName=;LegalCopyright=Copyright © 2015;FileDescription=Setup</VerInfo_Keys>
```

However, near the end of .dproj file there is another set of Version Info entries, covered by `VersionInfo` and `VersionInfoKeys`.

```
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1050</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1250</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
```

Apparently deleting those entries (that contain obviously wrong values) is safe thing to do. Question is do they still serve any purpose, or are they just some left over junk from the past?

---

Here is full .dproj file for completeness.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{DA1E4711-0D57-4F8C-8C46-1167D19D0848}</ProjectGuid>
        <MainSource>Setup.dpr</MainSource>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Release</Config>
        <TargetedPlatforms>3</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Application</AppType>
        <FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>
        <ProjectVersion>14.6</ProjectVersion>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win64' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win64)'!=''">
        <Base_Win64>true</Base_Win64>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_2)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_2_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2_Win32>true</Cfg_2_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_2</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_Build>501</VerInfo_Build>
        <VerInfo_MajorVer>5</VerInfo_MajorVer>
        <DCC_MapFile>2</DCC_MapFile>
        <Icon_MainIcon>Setup_Icon.ico</Icon_MainIcon>
        <Manifest_File>Setup.manifest.txt</Manifest_File>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <DCC_ImageBase>00400000</DCC_ImageBase>
        <DCC_Namespace>Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;$(DCC_Namespace)

</DCC_Namespace>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <VerInfo_Keys>FileVersion=5.0.0.501;ProductVersion=5.0;CompanyName=;LegalCopyright=Copyright © 2015;FileDescription=Setup</VerInfo_Keys>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win64)'!=''">
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>false</DCC_DebugInformation>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2_Win32)'!=''">
        <Debugger_RunParams>/file:Setup.0 /start:0</Debugger_RunParams>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="$(MainSource)">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <DCCReference Include="DataF.pas">
            <Form>Data</Form>
            <DesignClass>TDataModule</DesignClass>
        </DCCReference>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType/>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">Setup.dpr</Source>
                </Source>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1050</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1250</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
            </Delphi.Personality>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win64">True</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>
    <Import Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj" Condition="Exists

('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')"/>
</Project>
```

Comment: This is why I won't let the IDE anywhere near this part of my executables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Once you have all settings in place it is easy to monitor unwanted changes through VCS.

Comment: Once I have it all scripted it requires no effort at all to roll changes out. For instance Windows 10 entry in manifest.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My manifest is in separate file anyway, I just need to connect it with IDE.

Comment: also see: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/